# Why is my Tic-Tac-toe giving two wins to X win they win?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

```html
<html>
  <body>
<style>
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  let O1 = false;
  let X1 = false;
  let O2 = false;
  let X2 = false;
  let O3 = false;
  let X3 = false;
  let O4 = false;
  let X4 = false;
  let O5 = false;
  let X5 = false;
  let O6 = false;
  let X6 = false;
  let O7 = false;
  let X7 = false;
  let O8 = false;
  let X8 = false;
  let O9 = false;
  let X9 = false;
  let turn = 0;
  let XWinNum = 0
  let OWinNum = 0
  function Xon1() {
    if (O1 === false && X1 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'X';
      X1 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon2() {
    if (O2 === false && X2 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 'X';
      X2 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon3() {
    if (O3 === false && X3 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'X';
      X3 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon4() {
    if (O4 === false && X4 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = 'X';
      X4 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon5() {
    if (O5 === false && X5 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'X';
      X5 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon6() {
    if (O6 === false && X6 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = 'X';
      X6 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon7() {
    if (O7 === false && X7 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'X';
      X7 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon8() {
    if (O8 === false && X8 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = 'X';
      X8 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function Xon9() {
    if (O9 === false && X9 === false && turn === 0) {
      document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = 'X';
      X9 = true;
      turn++
      setTimeout(compMove, 1000);
    }
  }
  function compMove() {
    checkForWin()
    if (turn === 1) {
      if(X1 === true && X2 === true && X3 === false && O3 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'O';
      O3 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X1 === true && X3 === true && X2 === false && O2 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 'O';
      O2 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X2 === true && X3 === true && X1 === false && O1 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'O';
      O1 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X3 === true && X4 === true && X5 === false && O5 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
      O5 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X3 === true && X5 === true && X7 === false && O7 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'O';
      O7 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X4 === true && X5 === true && X6 === false && O6 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = 'O';
      O6 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X7 === true && X8 === true && X9 === false && O9 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = 'O';
      O9 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X7 === true && X9 === true && X8 === false && O8 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = 'O';
      O8 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X8 === true && X9 === true && X7 === false && O7 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'O';
      O7 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X1 === true && X4 === true && X7 === false && O7 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'O';
      O7 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X1 === true && X7 === true && X4 === false && O4 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = 'O';
      O4 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X7 === true && X4 === true && X1 === false && O1 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'O';
      O1 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X2 === true && X5 === true && X8 === false && O8 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = 'O';
      O8 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X2 === true && X8 === true && X5 === false && O5 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
      O5 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X5 === true && X8 === true && X2 === false && O2 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 'O';
      O2 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X3 === true && X6 === true && X9 === false && O9 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = 'O';
      O9 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X3 === true && X9 === true && X6 === false && O6 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = 'O';
      O6 = true
      turn-- 
      }
      if(X9 === true && X6 === true && X3 === false && O3 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'O';
      O3  = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X5 === true && X7 === true && X3 === false && O3 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'O';
      O3 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X5 === true && X3 === true && X7 === false && O7 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'O';
      O7 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X7 === true && X3 === true && X5 === false && O5 === false && turn === 1) {
        document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
      O5 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X1 === true || X2 === true || X3 === true || X4 === true || X5 === true || X6 === true || X7 === true || X8 === true || X9 === true && turn === 1) {
        if(O5 === false && X5 === false){
      document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
      O5 = true
      turn--} else {
      if(X1 === false && O1 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = 'O';
      O1 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X2 === false && O2 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = 'O';
      O2 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X3 === false && O3 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = 'O';
      O3 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X4 === false && O4 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = 'O';
      O4 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X5 === false && O5 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = 'O';
      O5 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X6 === false && O6 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = 'O';
      O6 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X7 === false && O7 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = 'O';
      O7 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X8 === false && O8 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = 'O';
      O8 = true
      turn--
      }
      if(X9 === false && O9 === false && turn === 1){
          document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = 'O';
      O9 = true
      turn--
      }
     
      }
      
      }
   
      }
      checkForWin()
      }
      function checkForWin() {
      if(X1 === true && X2 === true && X3 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X4 === true && X5 === true && X6 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X7 === true && X8 === true && X9 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X1 === true && X4 === true && X7 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X2 === true && X5 === true && X8 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X3 === true && X6 === true && X9 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X1 === true && X5 === true && X9 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(X3 === true && X5 === true && X7 === true){
      setTimeout(XWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O1 === true && O2 === true && O3 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O4 === true && O5 === true && O6 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O7 === true && O8 === true && O9 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O1 === true && O4 === true && O7 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O2 === true && O5 === true && O8 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O3 === true && O6 === true && O9 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O1 === true && O5 === true && O9 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      if(O3 === true && O5 === true && O7 === true){
      setTimeout(OWins, 100)
      turn+=2
      }
      }
      function OWins() {
        alert("O Wins")
        OWinNum+=1
        document.getElementById("win").innerHTML = 'X:' + XWinNum + '-' + 'O:' + OWinNum
      }
      function XWins() {
        alert("X Wins")
        XWinNum+=1
        document.getElementById("win").innerHTML = 'X:' + XWinNum + '-' + 'O:' + OWinNum
      }
      function Restart() {
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("6").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("7").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("8").innerHTML = '-'
        document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = '-'
        turn = 0
        X1 = false
        X2 = false
        X3 = false
        X4 = false
        X5 = false
        X6 = false
        X7 = false
        X8 = false
        X9 = false
        O1 = false
        O2 = false
        O3 = false
        O4 = false
        O5 = false
        O6 = false
        O7 = false
        O8 = false
        O9 = false
      }
</script>
  <table>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><button id="1" onclick="Xon1()">-</button></td>
  <td align="center"><button id="2" onclick="Xon2()">-</button></td>
  <td align="center"><button id="3" onclick="Xon3()">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><button id="4" onclick="Xon4()">-</button></td>
  <td align="center"><button id="5" onclick="Xon5()">-</button></td> 
  <td align="center"><button id="6" onclick="Xon6()">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center"><button id="7" onclick="Xon7()">-</button></td>
  <td align="center"><button id="8" onclick="Xon8()">-</button></td>
  <td align="center"><button id="9" onclick="Xon9()">-</button></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="Restart()">Restart</button>
  <h4 id="win"></h4>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hey I am new to stack overflow and yes I know it's a lot of code but I'm working on learning loops and arrays to shorten it. Back to the point. Can anybody tell me why X gets two wins whenever they win. (To win go to the middle right, then bottom left, then bottom right, then top right.) It would be much appreciated if anybody could tell me why it is doing this. It would also be nice if anybody could give me a good link to learn loops and arrays that isn't too confusing.

I need it to stop giving X two wins when they win. I have tried to copy and paste the O win and rename the variables so it applies to X and I also did the same for the function Xwins().

Comment: Ouch. This code desperately needs [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I am providing that link to point to a design pattern that coders all over the world find helpful, and I provided it as such. If you don't find it helpful, I am sorry. I will move to another question.

Comment: And it didn't answer my question of why X wins twice.

Comment: I thought you might wanted to look into the DRY principle. I was wrong. Also the comment section is not intended for providing answers. I am aware that your question is still open. But I'll leave it to somebody else.

Comment: Welp, I can't get x to win. so there's that.

Comment: If you follow the instructions on how to win. You should be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `compMove()` function `checkForWin()` calls two times. That's why it shows winner two times.

1. Beginning of the function
2. End of the function

When the 'O' wins just second `checkForWin()` works. But When the 'X' wins both `checkForWin()` is run.

**NOT:** You really need to work on your code skills. It's not a clean code example. You can look and learn somthing about SOLID and Clean Code.

Take a look at: https://gist.github.com/wojteklu/73c6914cc446146b8b533c0988cf8d29

Comment: Thank you so much I feel pretty stupid not noticing that. I'll take a took at the link I've been trying to clean it up up bit recently.